# Como Definir o Idioma da Atualização no WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Olá, pessoal.

Gostaria de entender o seguinte: ao acessar o menu: Painel > Atualizações em uma instalação do WordPress, existe a possibilidade de escolher entre atualizar o WP na versão Português do Brasil e Inglês:[http://prnt.sc/eh9eib]. No entanto, em outra instalação, existe somente a opção de atualizar/re-instalar para a versão em Inglês:[http://prnt.sc/eh6ho4]. No segundo exemplo, há poucos dias atrás atualizei manualmente para a versão 4.7.2 (Português), então, não entendo porque é exibido somente a opção de atualização para o idioma Inglês. Alguém sabe onde posso alterar isso?

O que determina se haverá um dou dois idiomas disponíveis na tela de atualização?

PS: Em configurações > Idioma já está configurado o idioma Português.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Dois fatores determinam se você vai ter um ou varias opções de instalação na sua tela:

1) é os idiomas setados no wordpress (via interface) ou via código

```
define ('WPLANG', '');
```

presente no wp-config.php ([veja o manual para mais detalhes](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Instalando_o_WordPress_em_seu_Idioma))

2) além do item acima é preciso que a comunidade oficial tenha liberado a atualização traduzida, caso a atualização ainda não tenha tradução ele só vai mostrar a opção de atualização em inglês.

Comment: Olá, @Danilo D

A versão 3.7.3 já foi traduzida, olhe só o print de um site que eu acabei de atualizar para a última versão: [http://prnt.sc/ehhaqt ]. Sendo assim, a outra instalação também deveria estar apresentando a opção de re-instalar em Português. Outra coisa, atualmente não é mais necessário adicionar o 'define('WPLANG','pt_BR');' para definir o idioma, isso é feito através do menu: Configurações > Geral > Idioma. De qualquer forma, adicionei essa linha no wp-config e não adiantou.